# Do I have to duplicate this function? - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqtouch

I'm using this function to create an transparent overlay of information over the current div for a web-based mobile app.

*Background: using jQTouch, so I have separate divs, not individual pages loading new.*

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.infoBtn').click(function() {
        $('#overlay').toggleFade(400);
        return false;    
     });
 });
```

Understanding that JS will run sequentially when i click the button on the first div the function works fine. When I go to the next div if I click the same button nothing "happens" when this div is displayed, but if i go back to the first div it has actually triggered it on this page.

So I logically duplicated the function and changed the CSS selector names and it works for both.

**But do I have to do this for each use?** Is there a way to use the same selectors, but load the different content in each variation?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? I'm assuming what you want is for different buttons to call `toggleFade` on different overlay divs.

```
function makeOverlayHandler(selector) {
    return function() {
        $(selector).toggleFade(400);
        return false;
    }
}

$('button selector').click(makeOverlayHandler('#overlay1'));
$('another button selector').click(makeOverlayHandler('#overlay2'));
```

You could also change `makeOverlayHandler`'s `selector` parameter to a jQuery object instead of a selector and call it like this: `makeOverlayHandler($('#overlay1'))`.

Comment: That is what I want to do. I'll look into this and see if it works out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This best way to do this is to make it all *relative*, so say you have markup like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay">Overlay content</div>
  <button class="infoBtn">Click to show overlay</button>
</div>
```

Then you can find the overlay for *this* button realtively, like this:

```
$(function() { //equivalent to $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.infoBtn').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.container').find('.overlay').toggleFade(400);
    return false;
  });
});
```

You can optimize this further, e.g. `.children('.overlay')` if the overlay is always a direct  child of container.  This goes from the current button (`this`), finds the `.container` it's in using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and then finds the `.overlay` inside of it using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).  With this approach you have one small bit of code to handle all your bindings, much easier to maintain :)